# (DIND) AWS ECS failed pull images, no space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm using docker in docker with ECS, currently cannot build big images, it failed in a pull step. The error is "no space left on device", even the disk still have more spaces. Please see the attachment, this images need to pull around 1.5GB.
I guess there is something wrong or limited in ECS config, because if I run this build container in another instance, it can build a big images.
Please advise me how to debug and fix this issue.
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

'dcloudbees/java-build-tools' requires 629 MB for compressed image plus 1.73GB for uncompressed.

Start investigation from `docker info`

I see you trying to use **docker-in-docker** or **docker-out-of-docker**. When you use **docker-in-docker**, you should use the same fs driver as on host docker.

Comment: The container parent are using vfs driver while ecs using devicemapper, so I have to change fs driver of container to devicemapper righ? this is a root cause of my issue?
Here is docker info https://pastebin.com/4tuxX26i

Comment: Yes. VFS have big overhead
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/vfs-driver/
_The VFS storage driver is not a union filesystem; instead, each layer is a directory on disk, and there is no copy-on-write support. To create a new layer, a “deep copy” is done of the previous layer. This leads to lower performance and more space used on disk than other storage drivers. However, it is robust, stable, and works in every environment. It can also be used as a mechanism to verify other storage back-ends against, in a testing environment._